# Is there a way to execute a bash script in Cygwin without explicitly typing bash my_script_name.sh?

Tags: bash, awk, cygwin

I have a bash script that contains an AWK program:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
awk -v ARPT_IDENT=$1 '
       BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
       $1 == ARPT_IDENT { print }' ANAV.TXT
```

I named the script file: `select-NAV-for-ARPT_IDENT.sh`

I can execute the script at a Cygwin command line like this:

```
bash select-ANAV-for-ARPT_IDENT.sh US01017
```

That works fine.

But, but, but, ...

I would really like to execute the script by just specifying the name of the script:

```
select-ANAV-for-ARPT_IDENT.sh US01017
```

Is there a way to execute a bash script in Cygwin without explicitly typing `bash ...`?

Note: I did try this: `chmod +x select-ANAV-for-ARPT_IDENT.sh`

And then executed it:

```
select-ANAV-for-ARPT_IDENT.sh US01017
```

But bash gave this error message:

```
-bash: select-ANAV-for-ARPT_IDENT.sh: command not found
```

Comment: You need to place the script to a directory contained in $PATH, too.

Comment: Ah! Got it.  I see that this works: ./select-ANAV-for-ARPT_IDENT.sh US01017

Comment: Cygwin emulates here the Linux-behaviour: The program must have the x-bit set, and it must have a `#!`  line.  Even then, a `bash x.sh` would execute a `$PWD/x.sh`, while typing just `x.sh` would not work; you have to type `./x.sh`. Omitting the directory part works only if the script happens to be in a directory mentioned in `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Either specify the path to the script, or save it to a directory that's present in the $PATH variable.